# Lua script access object path inside an array

Tags: redis, lua, redisjson

I'm trying to access the object with property `optionId = 'a386ead3-08ca-486e-aeb1-23add87292e7'` to set its weight.
my object is like following:

```
weight": {
            "options": [
              {
                "optionId": "a386ead3-08ca-486e-aeb1-23add87292e7",
                "weight": 10
              },
              {
                "optionId": "a386ead3-08ca-486e-aeb1-23add87292e7",
                "weight": 20
              }
            ],
            "value": 100
          }
```

and i'm using the following function to get its path but with no luck:

```
local GetFieldOptionWeightPath = function (optionId)
    return "$.weight.options[\"optionId\"==\""..optionId.."\"]";
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to compare each `optionId` like you would programmatically. To do that, you can use a filter script expression:

```
$.weight.options[?(@.optionId=="a386ead3-08ca-486e-aeb1-23add87292e7")]
```

Here, `$()` is the filter and `@` will point to each of the elements that's getting filtered.

Note that since it's a filter, it may potentially yield multiple results. In fact, in your example case it will yield both entries as they have the same `optionId`.

In the end your Lua function generating the path can look like:

```lua
local GetFieldOptionWeightPath = function (optionId)
    return ("$.weight.options[?(@.optionId==%q)]"):format(optionId)
end
```

This answer assumes [JSONPath](https://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/) support which was implemented in [RedisJSON v2](https://docs.redis.com/latest/modules/redisjson/release-notes/redisjson-2.0-release-notes/) (late 2021).